# Interface Declaring Struct

Tags: c#, interface

Why am I getting the error:

> Interfaces cannot declare types

The following is my code:

```
interface IExpression
{
    public struct Expression { }
}
```

Comment: `public` should not be there

Comment: Because an interface cannot indeed declare a type. They also can't have access qualifiers. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: and also, `struct` is a keyword and not a type

Comment: You can find more information here on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15009073/interfaces-cannot-declare-types. Aside you can solve this by using an abstract class instead.